# Bind multiple classes to a single variable

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

While using Tailwind with utility-first approach to css, I often find the need to bind multiple classes to a single variable.

For instance, to style an input form, I need to add `border-red`, `color-red`, etc if there is an error.

Is there a nice and elegant way to express this in Vue instead of writing `v-bind:class="{ 'border-red': error, 'text-red': error }`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine both classes into the same property:

```
:class="{ 'border-red text-red': error }"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another easy solution:

```
:class="error && 'border-red text-red'"
```

or for if, else

```
:class="error ? 'border-red text-red' : 'border-green'"
```

You also can concatenate strings to classnames:

```
:class="'border-'+borderColor"
```